# Updating dictionary in Python by key changing other keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary using two lists as keys

```
regions = ['A','B','C','D']
subregions = ['north', 'south']
region_dict = dict.fromkeys(regions, dict.fromkeys(subregions))
```

this produces the dictionay I want correctly:

```
{'A': {'north': None, 'south': None},
 'B': {'north': None, 'south': None},
 'C': {'north': None, 'south': None},
 'D': {'north': None, 'south': None}}
```

However, if I try to update one of elements in this dict, I see that other elements are also being updated

```
region_dict['A']['north']=1
>>> {'A': {'north': 1, 'south': None},
     'B': {'north': 1, 'south': None},
     'C': {'north': 1, 'south': None},
     'D': {'north': 1, 'south': None}}
```

I am not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here. How can I update just one of the values in this dictionary?

Comment: @zvone: It's the same symptom, but I don't consider `list` multiplication to be obviously similar to what `dict.fromkeys` does, at least for people with less Python experience. I did link that question in my answer, but it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Although the underlying causes are very similar, I agree it's not a duplicated question. Thanks for the very useful feedback

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `dict.fromkeys` when the value to use with each key is mutable; it uses *aliases* of the same value as the value for *every* key, so you get the same value no matter which key you look up. It's basically [the same problem that occurs with multiplying lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/364696). A simple solution is to replace the outer `dict.fromkeys` with a `dict` comprehension:

```
region_dict = {region: dict.fromkeys(subregions) for region in regions}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make you more clear.

Here `dict.fromkeys(subregions)` this is one separate object (which every key's value is pointed to), so whenever you change value of this object using one key, the same is going to get reflected on all the other keys referring to this object.

To explain through code, that would look something like this:

```py
temp = dict.fromkeys(subregions)
region_dict = {region: temp for region in regions}
```

So when you put `dict.fromkeys(subregions)` inside the `dict` comprehension, every time a new object is going to get created. That's the reason there will be no problem with that.